# Is rendezvous pronounced like run-they-who?

Tags: pronunciation, loan-words

I know that pronunciation in English is not very consistent, but I heard rendezvous being pronounced *like* `run`-`they`-`who`, which felt very strange. Is this really the right way to pronounce it, and how did it turn out like this?

Comment: Listen French/German pronounciation at: http://www.forvo.com/word/rendezvous/

Comment: Shouldn't this be at [French language and usage](http://french.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @gerrit If it is a French word, then maybe yes. I asked it here because it is an English word.

Comment: There is a French pronounciation here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AFr-rendez-vous-fr-Paris.ogg

Comment: A lot of the answers here are treating it as though it's a French word even when used in an English context. Sources indicate it was borrowed into English four centuries ago.

Comment: In general assuming that a foreign word that English has <strike>borrowed</strike>stolen is pronounced the same as in its source language is incorrect.  In addition to having its pronunciation frozen the way it was taken (as appears to be the case with rendezvous), changes in standard English pronunciation will often be carried over, and in many cases (especially for place names) if it doesn't appear wrong to do so by native speakers it will end up being pronounced as if it was of English origin.

Comment: When you steal something from somebody they don't also get to keep it. This makes linguistic borrowing unlike regular stealing or regular borrowing, but the only words we have for the concept are *borrowing* and *loanword*. Not to mention the fact that it was French that forced its way into English-speaking territory with the Norman invasion.

Comment: I removed the [tag:noun] tag because rendezvous is a verb as well as a noun, and its part of speech is not relevant to the question (which would make it a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in this instance).

Comment: @hippietrail  Actually, it was Stout Scandihoovians who cunningly stole French from its effete speakers and imposed it on the English - just as in the previous generation they imposed their own tongue on the English.

Answer (score 25):

**No,** not `run-they-who` but `ron-day-voo`.

---

Both Modern French and Modern English got the word *rendezvous* from Middle French. It's been an English word for [about four hundred and twenty years](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rendezvous)!

So simply saying it's a French word and we should mimic the modern French pronunciation is disingenuous.

English spelling is quirkier than its pronunciation. We've pretty much retained the French spelling (merely dropping the hyphen) but the pronunciation is quite different. French "r" is very different to any of the ways "r" is pronounced in English. French has nazalised vowels (the first "e" is one) but English does not.

(In fact it's quite possible that even the French meanings and pronunciation have drifted a little in the four centuries since English adopted this word.)

Both the Middle French and Modern French pronunciations are out of scope for this site for English learners. (They would be relevant in a forum, or in a linguistics site.)

The only pronunciation I know is like "ron-day-voo". Different dictionaries would render it different ways. The English Wiktionary currently uses:

> `/ˈɹɑndəˌvu/` or `/ˈɹɑndeɪ̯ˌvu/` for American English and `/ˈɹɒndɪˌvuː/` or `/'ɹɒndeɪ̯ˌvuː/` for British English.

Without the IPA these would be like `ron-duh-voo` and `ron-dee-voo`. These suggest that the second "e" can also be reduced like the "e" in chicken. But I'm not familiar with these pronunciations. These are both farther from the French pronunciation and perhaps a little closer to `run-they-who`.

Anyway, I would render the pronunciation I know in IPA this way:

`/rɒndeɪvuː/` (`ɒ` is the vowel in `hot`. In most American English accents this is usually affected by the ["cot-caught merger"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot-caught_merger#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger) and is rendered `ɑ` in IPA.)

Comment: @snailplane: I wanted it to stand out from the rest of my rambling (-: I guess I'll just pick one, bold, and ditch the all caps.

Comment: I can't think why OP hears it as *run-they-who*, but that certainly seems like the most important error to dismiss straight away. Anyway, defo +1 for making the point that the English pronounciation is just that - ***English***. I get fed up with people telling me I should pronounce such foreign imports using phonemes that simply don't exist in my language (even though in principle I'm prepared to attempt them if I'm actually speaking French, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The more I think about it, the more I think `run-they-who` could be based on an imperfect attempt to get the closest sound in English phonemes as possible to the Modern French pronunciation as possible. French nasalized "a" sounds more like an "o" to most English speakers than to an English "u" or "ah". I've been told Spanish "d" is closer to English "th" than English "d" so maybe the same is true of French "d". I don't think French "ez" is ever reduced to a schwa, though the dictionaries have told me some English pronunciations do reduce this part to schwa or "i"...

Comment: ... If French "v" is bilabial like in Spanish rather than labiodental like in English then "w" or even "b" is in some ways as good an approximation for their "v" as is our "v". Whoever devised this was either trying too hard, or possibly joking.

Comment: @hippie: Well, since we don't even bother attempting to replicate the sound of their capital city (which is *still* French, after all), I hardly see why we should bust a gut to do that with a word which we've indisputably "captured". It's ours now, so we can pronounce it how we want!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I totally agree - I'm just speculating on how somebody might've come up with the `run-they-who` idea.

Answer (score 20):

“Rendezvous” is a [loan word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rendezvous) — usually rendered like **ron-day-voo**¹ — which you can listen to **[here](http://fr.forvo.com/word/rendezvous/)**.

*Rendez-vous* is the French word for “appointment” (*date*, *gathering*).
Its English pronunciation is very much alike how the French pronounce it :

- (The [r] is a lost cause.)
- The [en] is that of *wand*, more or less.
- The [dez] is the [de] of *decorate*, only slightly more acute. (In fact, [ez] is *é* in French, but English only knows of the French *è*. It's close enough, really.)
- The [v] is that of *view*.
- The [ou] is like the English *oo* (*fool*). The *s* is silent.

---

¹ Or *run*, or *ran*, [even *ren*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-rendezvous-pronounced-like-run-they-who#comment1243_875).

<sup>Thanks to [afriza](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/872/is-rendezvous-pronounced-like-run-they-who#comment1156_872) for the link, to [hippietrail](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/889/57) for etymology, and to [user22911](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/899/57) for *de*.</sup>

Comment: This is just not correct. *Rendezvous* has, like many words of foreign origin, been in English for over four hundred years. So though its origins are still quite apparent it's absolutely an English word too. 400 years ago French did not even sound as it does today. Trying to pronounce it as though it's a Modern French word in the middle of an otherwise Modern English sentence is not good advice.

Comment: @hippietrail Some loan words (like "garage") quickly lose their conscious connection to their source language, while others (like "Rendezvous") never really lose the it in conscious communication. Even though *garage* was only borrowed about 100 years ago, hardly anyone who uses it  thinks of it as a French word, so its pronunciation  naturally drifts with English. *Rendezvous*, on the other hand may be 4 time older, but it is still very much thought of as a French word (whether loan or not), and so it naturally drifts with *French*, because English speakers try to make it sound like French.

Comment: +1, it's less common to also hear it pronounced ren-day-voo, but I have a few times.

Comment: This is quite true @RBarryYoung. I would dispute that most people feel some Frenchness when reading or hearing *rendezvous* or aim for Frenchness when using it. Though it's Frenchness is very obvious to many of us, I'm very sure there are as many people who would be surprised it's from French as are surprised it's not recent. It would be fun to look at a random corpus of uses to see its main contexts and collocations. Interestingly the `ron-di-voo`/`ron-duh-voo` are more Anglicized pronunciations than the `ron-day-voo` I prefer. It's probably the spelling that gives away it's Frenchness most.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski:  I would say ron-day-voo is what I hear.

Comment: @hippietrail I suppose we'll just have have to disagree on that then.  In my experience, although people who know the word *rendezvous* may not know its origin, the people who actually use it universally know(assume) that it is of French origin.  In fact, that's the *reason* that they do use it (instead of the perfectly serviceable word "*meeting*"), because of how it sounds.  It sounds French, and from the spelling, anybody with even high school French can easily tell that it must have a french origin.

Comment: For instance: For me, *rendezvous* has connotations such as spies meeting briefly in secret more than anything France-related. *Secret meeting* just doesn't have the same ring as *secret rendezvous*.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I dodn't totally disagree, just on some points. I found a great [online collation corpus](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/using-the-corpus) by Oxford Dictionaries. None of their common words occurring with *rendezvous* have any French connotation. Rather there are military, space, and romantic connotations, among other mundane ones: [*rendezvous* collocations](http://www.sketchengine.co.uk/ske.cgi?page=acd&article=an&language=English&str=rendezvous). Compare with [*meeting* collocations](http://www.sketchengine.co.uk/ske.cgi?page=acd&article=an&language=English&str=meeting)

Comment: ***rendezvous*** **collocations**: arrange, appoint, agree, become, make, have, death, comet, ship, romantic, secret, popular, general, next, first, point, mission, site, time, resort; ***meeting*** **collocations**: attend, hold, arrange, organise, convene, adjourn, observer, next, annual, regular, monthly, general, inaugural, room, committee, prayer, council, board, branch, creditor

Comment: @hippietrail You are confusing meaning/connotation with origin/pronunciation.  No one is saying that *Rendezvous* has or connotes frenchness in its meaning, but rather that it *sounds* as if it is a french word, and that this is exactly why people use it (and thus try to make it sound french).  This has nothing to do with implying something french about the meeting.  It is rather about either A) implying something sophisticated about the meeting by using the more "sophisticated" (foreign/french) word, or B) implying something sophisticated about the speaker for their apparent erudition.

Comment: I would say "rendezvous" does have sophisticated/erudite uses, but there are also domains in which it's just the usual word. If you read books or are involved in space stations or military missions you'll come across it being used plainly, rather than in an attempt for the speaker or writer to impress.

Comment: *[declarate](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Declarate)*??

Comment: I found the page you linked to for pronunciation confusing. Here's a simpler one: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rendezvous Just click on the speaker icon for the English pronunciation.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is pronounced /ˈɹɑndeɪ̯ˌvu/ (ron-day-voo). *Rendezvous* comes from the French *rendez-vous*, meaning a meeting or appointment, and its pronunciation was very much influenced by French pronunciation.

Comment: Literally, that's “[you] go [someplace]”, the person being indicated by the agreement, and the place being amiss. (And it's *vous*.)

Answer (score 5):

*Rendezvous* is a borrowing from French and still carries with it a French pronunciation, modified to fit available English sounds: `ˈrɑndeɪˌvu` (like *ron-day-voo*).

Answer (score 0):

Well! It's really very difficult for an American (all English speaking persons, in general—but not only for those) to pronounce "rendez-vous" (not "rendezvous"). The same difficulties that all peoples other than those of English mother tongue generally find in pronouncing English (US or GB).

Why is the pronunciation of "rendez-vous" so difficult?
First of all:

1. the French (like the Germans) have a very special way of "rolling" the letter **"r"**. You will find it very difficult if you have not learned to do so as a child. See   [Language Guide—French Pronunciation: Consonants](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronunciation/consonants.html).
2. Also: learning the the French nasal sound is, unquestionably, a difficult task. If you wish to exercise, please go to [Language Guide—French Pronunciation: Nasal Vowels](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronunciation/nasal.html).

To resume:
Do you really wish to pronounce "rendez-vous" like a real French person does? Or you could be satisfied just by pronouncing it in a decent way?
In my opinion the second option would be all right for you, especially because your listener would laugh at you!

**This is a sufficiently fine pronunciation for you**:

**run** (of **run** ning) + de (Letter **e** of demonstrate) + **voo** (of **voo**-doo)

**rundevoo**

Comment: Oh, *demonstrate* is exactly what I was looking for :·)

Comment: Actually the Germans have at least three different ways of rolling their "r", depending on where they're from. Sometimes like the French one, which comes from the same place the sound "g" comes from, sometimes like the Spanish one, which comes from the same place the sound "d" comes from, and then there's the one that's a rolling sound coming from the throat - the most striking one for me, and the hardest for me to try to mimic.

Comment: I disagree with this answer because it implies Anglophones should attempt to replicate the *French* pronunciation. I feel that's a completely untenable position.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers. This word has been current in English for more than 400 years and is no longer foreign.

Comment: I appreciate what StoneyB says. In fact the word (actually 2 words = "rendez" and "vous") is current in English and, therefore, it has to be considered as an English word. As an European linguist, however, I like to pronounce foreign words properly.
Therefore I insist in what I said: *"This is a sufficiently fine pronunciation for you (Americans): - **run** (of running) + **de** (Letter e of demonstrate) + **voo** (of voo-doo)"* **rundevoo** (try to roll the "r" like the Italians and Spaniards do)